# Python: asyncio loops with threads

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

Could you tell me if this is a correct approach to build several independent async loops inside own threads?

```
def init():
    print("Initializing Async...")
    global loop_heavy
    loop_heavy = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    start_loop(loop_heavy)

def start_loop(loop):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=loop.run_forever)
    thread.start()

def submit_heavy(task):
    future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(task, loop_heavy)
    try:
        future.result()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def stop():
    loop_heavy.call_soon_threadsafe(loop_heavy.stop)

async def heavy():
    print("3. heavy start %s" % threading.current_thread().name)
    await asyncio.sleep(3) # or await asyncio.sleep(3, loop=loop_heavy)
    print("4. heavy done")
```

Then I am testing it with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
    print("1. submit heavy: %s" % threading.current_thread().name)
    submit_heavy(heavy())
    print("2. submit is done")
    stop()
```

I am expecting to see `1->3->2->4` but in fact it is `1->3->4->2`:

```
Initializing Async...
1. submit heavy: MainThread
3. heavy start Thread-1
4. heavy done
2. submit is done
```

I think that I miss something in understanding async and threads.
Threads are different. Why am I waiting inside `MainThread` until the job inside `Thread-1` is finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why am I waiting inside `MainThread` until the job inside `Thread-1` is finished?

Good question, why are you?

One possible answer is, because you actually *want* to block the current thread until the job is finished. This is one of the reasons to put the event loop in another thread and use [`run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe).

The other possible answer is that you don't have to if you don't want. You can simply return from `submit_heavy()` the [`concurrent.futures.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) object returned by `run_coroutine_threadsafe`, and leave it to the caller to wait for the result (or [check if one is ready](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.done)) at their own leisure.

Finally, if your goal is just to run a regular function "in the background" (without blocking the current thread), perhaps you don't need asyncio at all. Take a look at the [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module, whose [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) allows you to easily submit a function to a thread pool and leave it to execute unassisted.

Comment: I don't want to block `MainThread`. If I return `Future` from `run_coroutine_threadsafe` back into the `MainThread` - the `MainThread` will be blocked by waiting until the `Future` is finished, isn't it?

Comment: @IgorZ No, it won't, that's the whole point of `Future`. (And be careful not to confuse asyncio Futures with concurrent.future Futures, although in this particular respect they're the same.) When you have a future object on your hands, you get to choose if and when to block waiting for its result.

Answer (score -1):

I will add one of the possible solutions that I found from the asyncio documentation.
I'm not sure that it is the correct way, but it works as expected (`MainThread` is not blocked by the execution of the child thread)

> [Running Blocking Code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#running-blocking-code)
>   Blocking (CPU-bound) code should not be called directly. For example, if a function performs a CPU-intensive calculation for 1 second, all concurrent asyncio Tasks and IO operations would be delayed by 1 second.
>   An executor can be used to run a task in a different thread or even in a different process to avoid blocking block the OS thread with the event loop. See the [loop.run_in_executor()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) method for more details.

Applying to my code:

```
import asyncio
import threading
import concurrent.futures
import multiprocessing
import time

def init():
    print("Initializing Async...")

    global loop, thread_executor_pool

    thread_executor_pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=loop.run_forever)
    thread.start()

def submit_task(task, *args):
    loop.run_in_executor(thread_executor_pool, task, *args)

def stop():
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.stop)
    thread_executor_pool.shutdown()

def blocked_task(msg1, msg2):
    print("3. task start msg: %s, %s, thread: %s" % (msg1, msg2, threading.current_thread().name))
    time.sleep(3)
    print("4. task is done -->")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
    print("1. --> submit task: %s" % threading.current_thread().name)
    submit_task(blocked_task, "a", "b")

    print("2. --> submit is done")
    stop()
```

Output:

```
Initializing Async...

1. --> submit task: MainThread
3. task start msg: a, b, thread: ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0
2. --> submit is done
4. task is done  -->
```

Correct me if there are still any mistakes or it can be done in the other way.

Comment: It's not correct because `run_in_executor` returns a future they you're supposed to await, which your code never does. If you just want to run a regular function "on the background" (without blocking the current thread), perhaps you don't need asyncio at all. Take a look at [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), which allows you to submit a function to a thread pool and leave it to execute unassisted.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. It is more like executing task in a background without using async at all. Thank you for this notice.

Comment: I've now updated my answer to cover the option of not using asyncio at all.